# Ruby: парисинг HTML страниц при момощи библиотеки nokogiri

Tags: парсер, ruby, https

Проблема в том, что не могу забрать HTML страницу с HTTPS

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/https'

url = "https://google.com/"
url = URI.parse( url )
http = Net::HTTP.new( url.host, url.port )
http.use_ssl = true if url.port == 443
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if url.port == 443
path = url.path
path += "?" + url.query unless url.query.nil?
res, data = http.get( path )

case res
  when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
    # parse link
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(data)
    doc.css('head').each do |link|
    #render_result.push(link.content)
    puts link
    end
   puts doc
  else
    return "failed" + res.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
doc = Nokogiri::HTML open(https_url)
```

Comment: И как с этим быть?

Comment: https_url = "https://google.com/"